# Grammaire question about COD

Tags: grammaire

I have read an article in [lemonde.fr](http://www.lemonde.fr/europe/article/2016/09/07/angela-merkel-met-en-garde-contre-la-montee-des-extremismes_4994180_3214.html). I got this sentence:

> L’Allemagne restera l’Allemagne, avec tout ce qui en elle nous est cher.

I see that `elle` is `l'Allemagne`. I want to ask about `nous` in the last sentence. How can I understand it? Is it `we` or `us`?

Comment: If *"nous"* was a subject (*"we"*), what would be its verb? *"est"* ? Impossible, *"est"* is the conjugated form of *"être"* in the third person singular.

Answer (score 2):

*Nous* is a personal pronoun, it has the same form when it is subject or when it is object, but its place in the sentence tells us what it is.

> tout ce qui en elle nous est cher

The subject of *est* is the relative pronoun *ce qui* (standing for *tout*). It is placed before *elle* and *nous*, *en elle* being a phrase of place  and *nous* an attributd (it can**not** be COD).

Comment: AFAIKm _être_ being a copula introduces attribute of its subject and does not have direct or indirect objects. I'd have analyzed _en elle_ as a complement of _ce qui_ and _nous_ as a complement of _cher_ (cfr. _tout en elle est cher à notre cœur_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Quite right and I'm aware I erred  by trying to oversimply   my explanation. In fact I was hoping someone would answer...